# how to make some child items 50% wide and side by side in flex-direction column container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I using bootstrap 4 `.navbar-nav`.

Here is a full live demo on codeply https://www.codeply.com/go/Zib61kYY2M

When the `.navbar-nav` goes into mobile collapsed mode on the set breakpoint.

These styles below are applied, and creates a nice stacked list of the navbar buttons.

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

But I need to control the width of the last two child `.nav-item`. And I need the items to appear side by side.

Is this possible with flex?

This currently how the nav looks...

[image]

This is how I want the last two items to look...

[image]

I've added 2 classes the last 2 items called `.nav-account`, so I just need to set some css like this...

```
.nav-account {
   width: 50%;
   ...
}
```

So make the last 2 items 50% wide and next to each other.

Full code below and here https://www.codeply.com/go/Zib61kYY2M

```
<ul class="navbar-nav flex-lg-grow-1 text-center text-lg-right">
    <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">FAQ's</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item nav-account ml-lg-auto">
        <a class="nav-link" href="https://dev.thesweetpeople.co/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.thesweetpeople.co%2Fprofile">Log in</a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item nav-account">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/register"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-user-plus color-sweets"></i> Register</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

1. Add `flex-wrap flex-row` classes to your `ul` (this sets the *flex-direction* always as `row` and set *flex-wrap*)
2. Add `col-12 col-lg-auto` to your `nav-items` expect the last two (sets 100% `flex-basis` in mobile view)
3. Add `col-6 col-lg-auto` to the last two `nav-items` (sets 50% `flex-basis` for the last two items in mobile view)

See demo below:

```css
.navbar {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
.navbar-hide {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
.nav-item {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Flex direction</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-lg-grow-1 text-center text-lg-right flex-wrap flex-row">
      <li class="nav-item col-12 col-lg-auto active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item col-12 col-lg-auto">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item col-12 col-lg-auto">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item col-12 col-lg-auto">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">FAQ's</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item col-12 col-lg-auto">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item nav-account ml-lg-auto col-6 col-lg-auto">
        <a class="nav-link" href="https://dev.thesweetpeople.co/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.thesweetpeople.co%2Fprofile">Log in</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item nav-account col-6 col-lg-auto">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/register"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-user-plus color-sweets"></i> Register</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<main role="main" class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Flex direction</h1>
    <p class="lead">My question, in mobile mode, is it possible to make the the <strong>register</strong> and <strong>login</strong> buttons 50% wide and side by side using flex?</p>
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/" role="button">View flex docs »</a>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you this seems to work, not as simple as I was hoping for, but the non-less its works perfectly. Nice one!

Answer (score 2):

One solution can be wrapping the last two `<li>` items inside next element:

```
<div class="ml-lg-auto d-inline-flex">
  ...
</div>
```

And then add classes `w-50` to both of they.

## Example:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Flex direction</a>
  
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-lg-grow-1 text-center text-lg-right">
      <li class="nav-item active border">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item border">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item border">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item border">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">FAQ's</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item border">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>

      <div class="ml-lg-auto d-inline-flex">
        <li class="nav-item nav-account w-50 border">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Log in</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item nav-account w-50 border">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/register">
            <i class="fas fa-fw fa-user-plus color-sweets"></i>
            Register
          </a>
        </li>
      </div>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Here is another version, that use nested `<li>` and `<ul>` items to don't fall on usage of invalid markup as mentioned on the commentaries:

## Alternative version:

```css
.custom-ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Flex direction</a>
  
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-lg-grow-1 text-center text-lg-right">
      <li class="nav-item active border">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item border">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item border">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item border">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">FAQ's</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item border">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>

      <li class="ml-lg-auto">
        <ul class="custom-ul d-flex">
          <li class="nav-item nav-account w-50 border">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Log in</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item nav-account w-50 border">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/register">
              <i class="fas fa-fw fa-user-plus color-sweets"></i>
              Register
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: `ul` should only have `li` as children... yet, its working fine

Comment: I thought this was the winning answer at first but I can't bring my self to use invalid markup. Appreciate the answer and good know for non list stuff. +1 for the inline trick.

Comment: @joshmoto I have included an alternative version based on both commentaries, so there is no invalid markup. Just in case this is useful to someone. Anyway, thank for appreciate the effort!